# ORA-00911 Error when trying to insert through JDBC in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbc

I do have a system that changes a placeholder by its value before sending the request to the database.

```sql
INSERT INTO MYAPP.LOGPRODUCAO
(NOMERECURSOCONJUNTO, ORDEMPRODUCAO, OPERACAO, QTDEBOAS, INICIO, FIM, MATRICULAFUNCIONARIO, STATUS)
VALUES(
    {nomeRecursoConjunto},
    CAST({ordemProducao} as VARCHAR(100)),
    {operacao},
    TO_NUMBER({qtdeBoas}),
    TO_TIMESTAMP({inicio}, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3'),
    TO_TIMESTAMP({fim}, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3'),
    {matriculaFuncionario},
    {status})
```

After replacing, it becomes something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO MYAPP.LOGPRODUCAO
(NOMERECURSOCONJUNTO, ORDEMPRODUCAO, OPERACAO, QTDEBOAS, INICIO, FIM, MATRICULAFUNCIONARIO, STATUS)
VALUES(
    'NAME',
    CAST(43267 as VARCHAR(100)),
    10,
    TO_NUMBER('0.0'),
    TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-20T14:40:43.819', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3'),
    TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-20T15:28:28.359', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3'),
    2389,
    'I')
```

When I take the query above and execute through DBeaver, it works. The row is inserted.
When I'm running through a JDBC it returns the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: caractere inválido
    at 
...
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: caractere inválido
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:213)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:37)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:896)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1119)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1661)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1626)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:282)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: Error : 911, Position : 137, Sql = INSERT INTO MYAPP.LOGPRODUCAO
(NOMERECURSOCONJUNTO, ORDEMPRODUCAO, OPERACAO, QTDEBOAS, INICIO, FIM, MATRICULAFUNCIONARIO, STATUS)
VALUES(
    'NAME',
    CAST(43267 as VARCHAR(100)),
    10,
    TO_NUMBER('0.0'),
    TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-20T14:40:43.819', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3'),
    TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-20T15:28:28.359', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3'),
    2389,
    'I'), OriginalSql = INSERT INTO MYAPP.LOGPRODUCAO
(NOMERECURSOCONJUNTO, ORDEMPRODUCAO, OPERACAO, QTDEBOAS, INICIO, FIM, MATRICULAFUNCIONARIO, STATUS)
VALUES(
    'NAME',
    CAST(43267 as VARCHAR(100)),
    10,
    TO_NUMBER('0.0'),
    TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-20T14:40:43.819', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3'),
    TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-20T15:28:28.359', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3'),
    2389,
    'I'), Error Msg = ORA-00911: caractere inválido
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
    ... 66 more
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR` in Oracle?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is how the stack trace is printed but it seems it might be inserting a `,` at the end of the SQL sentence.

Comment: I changed the query to cast to VARCHAR2. It gives the same error.
The comma was added by the stacktrace, is not part of the query.

Comment: *"I do have a system that changes a placeholder by its value before sending the request to the database"* Get rid of that system, it is horrendous. Building SQL statements using string concatenation with user-supplied text values!!!! *<Yikes>*

Comment: Do you need the `CAST(43267 as VARCHAR(100))`? Can you change it just simply to `'43267'`? Or maybe replace it for `TO_CHAR(43267)` as well.

Comment: Seeing such things as `CAST(43267 as VARCHAR(100))` (i.e. cast number to string) and `TO_NUMBER('0.0')` (transform string to number without defining the format, i.e. depending of the session NLS setting!) I can't resist the idea you are simply asking for troubles. Use **bind variables**, handle *numbers* as *numbers* and *strings* as *strings*, this will solve the problem. Check if you don't use a `;` as trailing character

Comment: @FrancoPan, I tested your query and it looks ok. The error is referring to character 137, which it is the last character of VALUES before the parenthesis.  Try to see if you have any hidden character there in your Java code that you are not aware of.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Thank you. I'll try

Comment: @Andreas Before critisizing anything, it would be better to know the context. Generally, I would agree with you, but it makes sense under the purpose of the application. Your reply did not help me with the problem.